# How to get download location from javascript link?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to programmatically download a pdf from [a website](https://www.yourticketprovider.nl/LiveContent/tickets.aspx?x=492449&y=8687&px=92AD8EAA22C9223FBCA3102EE0AE2899510C03E398A8A08A222AFDACEBFF8BA95D656F01FB04A1437669EC46E93AB5776A33951830BBA97DD94DB1729BF42D76&rand=a17cafc7-26fe-42d9-a61a-894b43a28046&utm_source=PurchaseSuccess&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=SystemMails) in which the link loads some javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('downloadTop','')">Download</a>
```

Seeing that a wget or any comparable mechanism would obviously fail I decided to use selenium with Phantomjs to emulate a real browser and javascript interpreter to actually see what it does if I "click" on the download link. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052) Phantomjs currently does not support file download. The thing is that I don't even need to download the file using Phantomjs, I just want to get the direct url from the file so that I can simply download it using something like wget.

So I tried the following:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> link = 'https://www.yourticketprovider.nl/LiveContent/tickets.aspx?x=492449&y=8687&px=92AD8EAA22C9223FBCA3102EE0AE2899510C03E398A8A08A222AFDACEBFF8BA95D656F01FB04A1437669EC46E93AB5776A33951830BBA97DD94DB1729BF42D76&rand=a17cafc7-26fe-42d9-a61a-894b43a28046&utm_source=PurchaseSuccess&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=SystemMails'
>>> driver.get(link)
>>> for linkElement in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
...    print linkElement.get_attribute('href')
...    
https://www.yourticketprovider.nl/
javascript:__doPostBack('downloadTop','')
https://www.yourticketprovider.nl/LiveContent/tickets.aspx?x=492449&y=8687&px=92AD8EAA22C9223FBCA3102EE0AE2899510C03E398A8A08A222AFDACEBFF8BA95D656F01FB04A1437669EC46E93AB5776A33951830BBA97DD94DB1729BF42D76&rand=a17cafc7-26fe-42d9-a61a-894b43a28046&utm_source=PurchaseSuccess&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=SystemMails#
etc. etc.
```

Since I need to get the second element I tried the following:

```
>>> a = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[1].click()
>>> print a
None
```

and from here I'm kinda stuck.

Does anybody know how I can click that link and get the resulting download url? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Aren't you actually exposing your paid ticket through that link you shared?

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr: The link actually triggers hidden form `form#form1`

The correct way to figure these things out is to forget javascript and open your console, specifically the network panel. So what I did was that I opened the panel and I could clearly see:

[image: image description]

The **POST** here is important, it means it uses request using POST HTTP, so you can't just use `wget` to get it. Wget only allows you to define URL as far as I know. I could also inspect both GET (the `?blah=blah`) and POST (those go after request header) parameters:

[image: image description]

I noticed that the GET parameters match those in the URL you shared. So all you need is to copy the POST parameters. This code snippet can get'em from the hidden form:

```
function paramsToObject(form) {
  var fields = {};
  for(var i=0,l=form.length; i<l; i++) {
      fields[form[i].name] = form[i].value;
  }
  return fields;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(paramsToObject(document.forms[0])));
```

The URL also can be obtained by getting the form `target` attribute.

Comment: This indeed works, but the problem is that it is a custom solution. The underlying thing I want to achieve is that if I click a "download" button on any site (not just this one) it should behave like it does in a normal browser; simply download the file. Since this example already shows (thanks to you) that simply obtaining an url and `wget`ting that url does not always work (since this page does a POST before downloading the file), would you have any idea if there is a more generic method of doing this so that I can also use that method on different websites which have javascript links?

Comment: Well you can write a smart AI that analyses every of such pages, like I just did manually, and figures the solution out. Or you can make import script for every website you gather data from - this is what data concentration servers do AFAIK. Also I'll have you know that what you're up to is against terms of use of most websites, which is why they make downloading so obscure.